# c# code to vb.net conversion issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

i want to convert to c# the code from url below to vb.net for learning. i haven't learnt c# yet.
http://divyen.wordpress.com/2012/06/13/html5-developing-websocket-server-using-c-sharp-dot-net/

i had converted almost all the sources code to VB.Net with converter, the converted sources code have 1 bug
Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'Aggregate' accepts this number of arguments.

c# code

```
public UInt64 Length  
{  
get  
{  
return Payload.Aggregate    <ArraySegment<byte>, ulong>(0, (current, seg) => current +    Convert.ToUInt64(seg.Count));  
}  
}
```

converted VB.Net code

```
Public ReadOnly Property Length() As UInt64  
Get  
Return Payload.Aggregate(Of ArraySegment(Of Byte), ULong)(0, Function(current, seg) current +     Convert.ToUInt64(seg.Count))  
End Get  
End Property
```

may i know the equivalent code in VB.Net?

Comment: Take a look at http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/ and http://converter.telerik.com/ and http://www.dotnetspider.com/convert/csharp-to-vb.aspx

Comment: Do you have `System Linq` imported?

Comment: i had import System.Linq and System.Linq.Enumerable

Comment: SonerGönül, the other converter oso nt working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Public ReadOnly Property Length() As UInt64
Get
Return Payload.Aggregate(0, Function(current, seg) current + Convert.ToUInt64(seg.Count))
End Get
End Property
```

Comment: Great answer - this is a tough one to spot sometimes - the reason is that VB has problems with including the generic specifier on Enumerable extension method calls.  It's usually best just to leave it off (as you did).

Answer (score 0):

Should you insert an `Of` keyword before ULong

```
Return Payload.Aggregate(Of ArraySegment(Of Byte), Of ULong)(0, Function(current, seg) current + Convert.ToUInt64(seg.Count))
```

Comment: it show another error when i add of in frond of the ULong. **Keyword does not name a type.**

Answer (score 0):

In advance,use this to convert your code :

http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb

Comment: Note that this converter does not remove the generic specifier, which you have to remove in this case (see coder's answer).